# LineChart React-Native Custom Width

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, graph

I am receiving label and dataSet data from the API (I have large amount of labels)

I am currently giving LineChart dynamic width (label.length *10)

The Issue is when the width surpasses over 4000, the graph crashes and stops displaying...

Any solutions?

Thank you!

I tried setting up width dynamically e.g. (label.length * 10) and it works correct until 4000, after that it crashes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.